# C++ separate input into various variables

Tags: c++, string, parsing, tokenize

What is an elegant way of separating the console input (or a string) into two int variables?

Input format: `a - bx`

- a, b are integer always.
- x can be ignored.

Result:

```
int1 = a; 
int2 = -b;
```

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806074/c-extract-polynomial-coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming exactly the form stated:

```
int a, b;
std::string op;
std::cin >> a >> op >> b;
if (op == "-") b = -b;
```

Note that this isn't robust. It'll treat anything other than `-` as a plus, and will recognise absolutely any input that starts with a pair of numbers separated by a blob of non-whitespace.

Comment: Then it won't work. If you want a more robust solution, you'll need to build a small parser.

Answer (score 1):

Tokenize and parse string as math equation.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 and AXE here is a possible parser:

```
#include <axe.h>
#include <iostream>

template<class I>
void example(I i1, I i2)
{
    int a, b;
    auto space = axe::r_lit(' ');
    auto rule = axe::r_udecimal(a) & *space & axe::r_decimal(b);
    (rule >> axe::e_ref([&](...) 
    { std::cout << "\na=" << a << ",b=" << b; }))
    (i1, i2);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "100 - 10i";
    example(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

P.S. Beware of bugs in the above code: I have only proved it correct, not tried it.