# std::regex to identify coefficient of polynomial equation

Tags: c++, regex, polynomial-math, equation-solving

I am new to C++ and I am asked to create a solver of a second degree polynomial function. To do this, I first need to parse the equation and reduce it to show it in the reduced form, i.e:

`8 * X^0 - 6 * X^1 + 5.6 * X^2 = 3 * X^0` 
becomes 
`5 * X^0 - 6 * X^1 + 5.6 * X^2 = 0`

After hours looking at different syntaxes, I found that the following regex `[0-9]+(?=.?[*](?=.?(?=(X\^0))))` identify `8` and `3` as coefficients (still need to handle the negative sign tho).

My problem is, the following code with library `<regex>` seems to not give me `8` and `3` but the entire equation, I wonder why ? Because the code works in [regex online tester](https://regex101.com/) as a `full match 1` and `full match 2`. I wonder if this is not because I also have groups which are messing up a bit..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string var = "8 * X^0 - 6 * X^1 + 5.6 * X^2 = 3 * X^0";

    regex wsaq_re("[-](?=.?[0-9](?=.?[*](?=.?(?=(X^0)))))"); 
    copy( sregex_token_iterator(var.begin(), var.end(), wsaq_re, -1),
        sregex_token_iterator(),
        ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler? std::regex is known to be buggy on some versions of gcc, you may want to use one form boost

Comment: This seems like it would much more easily solved with a hand-written parser.

Comment: @pete-becker ok I found this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806074/c-extract-polynomial-coefficients?rq=1[link] which might be helpful

Comment: @salva compiler is `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lcxxrt -ldl -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create regex iterator:

```
sregex_token_iterator(var.begin(), var.end(), wsaq_re, -1)
```

-1 as the third parameter [means](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator)

> submatch  -   the index of the submatch that should be returned. "0"
>   represents the entire match, and "-1" represents the parts that are
>   not matched (e.g, the stuff between matches).

you should put 1 there.

Also your regex is overcomplicated IMHO, this one should be sufficient:

```
regex wsaq_re( "(=?\\s*\\-?\\s*\\d+\\s*\\*\\s*X\\s*\\^\\d+)");
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/EzDq8e) output is:

```
8 * X^0
- 6 * X^1
6 * X^2
= 3 * X^0
```